# Can I make Hamotzi on bread that is made without yeast?

Tags: halacha, blessing, hamotzi-beracha

Can Hamotzi be said on bread that is made with baking powder and baking soda and not yeast? Is yeast integral to its being considered bread?

Comment: Perhaps you might want to expand your question to explain why a non-yeast bread wouldn't be considered bread?

Comment: Note that this can be derived from the halachos of matzah which do not have yeast. IIRC thare is a difference between Ashkenazim and Sefardim about that. However, if Matza (flour and water only) is hamotzi, then the kind of bread that you ask about would also be hamotzi.

Comment: of interest: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30867/is-beer-bread-hamotzi

Answer (score 1):

Any bread made from the five grains (wheat, rye, oat, barley, spelt) will require Hamotzi.

See [OU.org](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/halacha-lmaaseh/hamotzi/)

Answer (score 1):

Many make hamotzi on matzo which does not contain yeast (and all make hamotzi on matzo on Pesach), so yes you can make Hamotzi on bread without yeast. Baking powder and baking soda should not detract from Hamotzi.

Comment: *All* make *Hamotzi* on *matzah* year round, provided it has a *tzuras hapas* (e.g. isn't just a snack cracker).

Comment: I think one should add a caveat that "tzurat hapat" and one of the 5 grains is insufficient on its own to have it as "hamnotzi". Fruit juice cannot be added to the batter, either, If it was, many opinions state that such bread is mezonot. Thus, you hav emezonot rolls, and many say that egg matzah is mezonot as well.